# Where do I put Minecraftlauncher.exe?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I accidentally moved *Minecraftlauncher.exe* out of its original folder and I'm not sure what folder to put it back into.

Can someone check on their computer what folder *Minecraftlauncher.exe* is in?

Comment: I'm not sure it matters where you keep the launcher.

Comment: @CloseVoters - How exactly is this 'unclear'?

Comment: And again, how is this 'Too Broad'?

Answer (score 6):

Wherever you want to. It doesn't actually matter, Minecraft always stores its data in the same place, `%APPDATA%/.minecraft`. (Or `~/.minecraft`, if you're on Linux.)

Comment: but im trying to get forge and it says i need to get a a luncher profile so i think that means it need to be in the original file that it was when it was downladed, i only need to know what folder minecraftlauncher.exe is in

Comment: Put launcher in your desktop! :)

Comment: If you want to get Forge, then you can just open the launcher, open a new profile, set the version of Minecraft to the version of the Minecraft Forge that you want to install (if you want to install Forge 1.8, set the version of Minecraft of the profile to Minecraft 1.8), then press play. After that, open a new world, and when you are loaded into the new world, close the game. Then you can install Forge 1.8. Forge Installer will install the profile for you automatically.

Answer (score 3):

The launcher is in the following path on my computer and on many others:

- Windows 7/8/8.1:
  `C:/Users/(your user name)/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/launcher`
- Windows XP (or perhaps even older):
  `C:/Documents and settings/(your user name)/AppData/.minecraft/launcher`

Note: `C:` is the default system partition. If your computer has a different system partition,replace `C:` with the corresponding letter. You can also run Minecraft no matter where the launcher is.

Comment: i put that in my start search and it didnt show up it said no items match your search

Comment: It is a path,not an item. Open it manually by launching "Computer".@GargantuanGaming